# Ajax.BeginForm JavaScript callback with parameter causes $(this) to refer to window instead of form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using the following code to create a form with JS callbacks:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Example", "Example", null, new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnBegin = "ajaxFormBegin",
    OnSuccess = "ajaxFormSuccess(data, status, xhr, 'exampleValue')"
}
```

I have found that if I don't pass a parameter to the callback, as is the case with the OnBegin callback, then the JQuery $(this) variable refers to the calling form.

If I do pass a parameter, as is the case with the OnSuccess callback, $(this) refers to the window. I want it to refer to the form as in the first scenario.

```
function ajaxFormBegin() {
    $form = $(this); // Refers to calling form
}
function ajaxFormSuccess(data, status, xhr, callback_) {
    $form = $(this); // Refers to window 
}
```

Is this expected behavior or is my implementation wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assignment to `OnSuccess` is a function **call** in global context.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Example", "Example", null, new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnBegin = "ajaxFormBegin",
    OnSuccess = "ajaxFormSuccessWrapper"
}

<script>
function ajaxFormSuccessWrapper(data, status, xhr) {
  var form = this; 
  ajaxFormSuccess(data, status, xhr, 'exampleValue'); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying but trying your code gives me an error:  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Comment: (function(data,status,xhr
/**/) {
function(data, status, xhr) { var $form = this; ajaxFormSuccess(data, status, xhr, 'changePasswordSuccess'); }
})

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Unfortunately declaring the function defeats the object of being able to pass the value in from the assignment but you have given me the steer I needed. I've started debugging the unobtrusive library to see exactly what is going on and in which context the calls are made.